# Standard API Protocol for ECM Systems?

Tags: enterprise-architecture, enterprise-development, document-databases, document-management

I am wondering if there is an established standard or protocol when working with APIs for document management systems or ECMs. For example, let's say I'm working on a new product and I want it to have support for both FileNet and Documentum. Is there a protocol established across the major ECM systems that I could target my application for? This may very well not exist, so I'm asking because I'm sure one of you will know.

Answer (score 1):

Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) was an attempt at standardization:

> Ovum urges organizations to take a "solutions view" to ECM by thinking about their pain-points and then shortlisting vendors that provide solutions that best address these issues. Consider mixing and matching solutions from different vendors to create a best-of-breed approach to ECM. However, this will require integration between different vendors' products, so ensure that the solutions selected adhere to CMIS (Content
>   Management Interoperability Services), the standard for interoperability between content management systems

**References**

- [EMC Documentum Content Management Interoperability
  Services (CMIS) (pdf)](http://www.jouvinio.net/wiki/images/a/a4/Documentum_cmis_6.7_deployment.pdf)
- [IBM FileNet Content Manager Implementation Best Practices and Recommendations (pdf)](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247547.pdf)
- [Ovum Decision Matrix: Selecting an Enterprise Content Management Solution, 2015–16 (pdf)](https://www.emc.com/collateral/analyst-reports/ovum-ECM-decision-matrix.pdf)
- [CMIS: An Open API for Managing Content](https://www.slideshare.net/jpotts/cmis-an-open-api-for-managing-content)
- [Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) in SharePoint | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/content-management-interoperability-services-cmis-in-sharepoint)
- [CMIS Connector // MuleSoft Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/cmis-connector)
- [Content Management System Integration Guide (pdf)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60665_01/otmcs_gs/OTMCI/OTMCI.pdf)